# Magento Zend_Date_Exception Invalid year

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I am receiving this error in my exception log but have not found anything on resolving this issue.

```
exception 'Zend_Date_Exception' with message 'Invalid year, it must be between -10000 and 10000' in /var/www/websitename/web/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php:5002

#0 /var/www/webstiename/web/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php(2671): Zend_Date->mktime('08', '29', '52', 1, 27, 292277022657, false)
```

I only noticed this exception when we moved the web to a new development server. I also only looked in the exception.log file because when I was adding products to the shopping cart and I was getting resolved to a blank white screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most probably be caused by the change in the `timezone` ,

Happens sometime in the event of the host changing , which has different `timezone`

try to change the timezone of your mysql,

You can update the time zone using the direct SQL request in phpMyAdmin of your server

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'America/New_York' WHERE `path` = 'general/locale/timezone'
```